# PYTHONPATH Error [Windows 123] with Pyspark when use import lazy like NLTK or PATTERN duplicate label disk 'C://C://..spark-core_2.11-2.3.2.jar'

Tags: python, windows, apache-spark, pyspark, nltk

The problem is that the Windows path and libraries are imported lazily, like nltk, means that nltk and pattern import their libraries when they are used, and at this moment the module importlib_metada.py and pathlib.py try to read PYTHONPATH with a Incorrect value in the path (D: / D: /), then the code explodes.

First, we have a simple function like this

```
import nltk
def print_stopwords():
  print(nltk.corpus.stopwords)
```

In local mode, you can run this and you get all the stop words, **OK**.

If you want to use this function inside a map from Spark, to implements a Pyspark workflow, the code above is not working. Why? I really dont know...

I think the reason why it doesn't work is due to the Spark JAVA libraries that use and modify the PYTHONPATH when they do a map function like this:

```
import nltk
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, SparkSession

spark = (SparkSession
         .builder
         .master("local[*]")
         .appName("Nueva")
         .getOrCreate())

sc = spark.sparkContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

def print_stopwords(x):
    print("\n",x)
    print(nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english'))
    return x

prueba = sc.parallelize([0,1,2,3])
r = prueba.map(print_stopwords)
r.take(1)
```

I get the error

```
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\__init__.py", line 143, in <module>
    from nltk.chunk import *
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\chunk\__init__.py", line 157, in <module>
    from nltk.chunk.api import ChunkParserI
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\chunk\api.py", line 13, in <module>
    from nltk.parse import ParserI
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\parse\__init__.py", line 100, in <module>
    from nltk.parse.transitionparser import TransitionParser
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\parse\transitionparser.py", line 22, in <module>
    from sklearn.datasets import load_svmlight_file
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .twenty_newsgroups import fetch_20newsgroups
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\twenty_newsgroups.py", line 44, in <module>
    from ..feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import text
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 28, in <module>
    from ..preprocessing import normalize
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from ._function_transformer import FunctionTransformer
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_function_transformer.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ..utils.testing import assert_allclose_dense_sparse
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\testing.py", line 718, in <module>
    import pytest
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytest.py", line 6, in <module>
    from _pytest.assertion import register_assert_rewrite
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\assertion\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _pytest.assertion import rewrite
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\assertion\rewrite.py", line 26, in <module>
    from _pytest.assertion import util
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\assertion\util.py", line 8, in <module>
    import _pytest._code
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\_code\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .code import Code  # noqa
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\_code\code.py", line 23, in <module>
    import pluggy
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pluggy\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .manager import PluginManager, PluginValidationError
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 11, in <module>
    import importlib_metadata
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 549, in <module>
    __version__ = version(__name__)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 511, in version
    return distribution(distribution_name).version
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 482, in distribution
    return Distribution.from_name(distribution_name)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 183, in from_name
    dist = next(dists, None)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 425, in <genexpr>
    for path in map(cls._switch_path, paths)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 449, in _search_path
    if not root.is_dir():
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pathlib.py", line 1351, in is_dir
    return S_ISDIR(self.stat().st_mode)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pathlib.py", line 1161, in stat
    return self._accessor.stat(self)
OSError: [WinError 123] The file name, directory name or volume label syntax is not correct: 'C:\\C:\\Enviroments\\spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7\\jars\\spark-core_2.11-2.3.2.jar'
```

I print the environment variables from pathlib.py and importlib_metadata.py and get the PYTHONPATH values ​​like this:

```
'PYTHONPATH': 'C:\\Enviroments\\spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7\\python\\lib\\pyspark.zip;C:\\Enviroments\\spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7\\python\\lib\\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip;/C:/Enviroments/spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/spark-core_2.11-2.3.2.jar'
```

I try to edit the path inside the function, outside, and all the ways...but in some moment Spark serialize the function and edit the PYTHONPATH... no in python files, in Java files, and I cant debug this code because the spark runs inside a container, with an ip and port that I cant enter for a lot of complex reason of my IDE (Intellij Idea).

The reason not work is because of this slash -> /C:/Enviroments/spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/spark-core_2.11-2.3.2.jar'. The python interprets this slash in windows like an absolute path and add the disk label at the beginning of the path, /C: => C:/C:/. Then in execution it generates the error that this route, obviously, DOES NOT EXIST.

PLEASE HELP ME!
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if use new conda environment in another drive letter, maybe because the importlib package is installed and used in the base conda env, but is not executed in new conda environments. I don't know why.

Python with conda environments do not work properly with the base conda env, it needs to use another conda environment in another dirve (for example D: if have Conda installed on C: Drive)

To make this, you can change the PYSPARK_PYTHON enviroments variables:

```
os.environ["PYSPARK_PYTHON"]="D:\\conda_envs\\new_environment\\python.exe"
os.environ["SPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON"]="D:\\conda_envs\\new_environment\\python.exe"
```

Make sure that you have the SPARK_HOME directory in the same drive letter as the Python, or anaconda environment.

¯\*(ツ)*/¯
Whatever

FINALLY RESOLVED T.T

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue using pytest. I do not have a proper solution for malformed path in windows.

You can apply a quickfix to it as such :

```
for path in list(sys.path):
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        sys.path.remove(path)
```

You will at least get rid of the error.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but I try and I have the same problem, maybe I dont implement in the right place (inside the map function), but... I think I have the solution...I posted the answer, but thanks again.